# In MySQL, what is different between "WHERE IN" and "WHERE"?

Tags: php, mysqli

Till now I still cannot differentiate between `WHERE` clause and `WHERE IN` clause. For example, I have:

`Query = mysqli($mysql_connect, "SELECT * From Customer Where CustomerID IN ('CU001', 'CU002', 'CU003')");`

Is this same as `Query = mysql($mysql_connect, "SELECT * FROM Customer Where CustomerID = 'CU001' AND CustomerID= 'CU002' AND CustomerID='CU003')";`?

If it the same, which one is the best practice to follow? Thanks.

Comment: The second one cannot be valid. `IN` replaces `OR`, not `AND`. [Here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-in-clause.htm) you can find information and an example.

Comment: it should be `OR` not `AND`

Comment: this is i'm not sure it is equals `OR` or `AND` Operator, and can we use `WHERE IN` with only one or two Condition like  `WHERE CustomerID IN ('CU001')`, can we use like this?

Comment: @HouyNarun your value can not be equal to 2 or more values at a time. Your upper query looks like `WHERE 1=1 and 1=2 and 1=3` and this is not logical, so it obviously is equal to `or`. I think you ~~can, but there is no need~~ should not use it for 1 value. For such question **Can I ....?** just try and you'll see :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **WHERE** clause can be combined with AND, OR and NOT operators. The AND and OR operators are used to filter records based on more than one condition. The AND operator displays a record if all the conditions separated by AND is **TRUE** but should not be used for single column as you have used in 2nd query (it will not find any record).

The **In** operator finds all records which falls within specified values, like OR condition.

Comment: Dhrunvil Patel, very thanks it makes clear to me that the 'WHERE IN' clause is like the many conditions with 'OR' operator. I hope to use it wisely with other sql related language because I always use only where clause . Also credit to @Danielius for your helpful comments and resource , Cheers :)